# d3js timeline adding current month renders multiple rectangles and doesn't clear

Tags: d3.js, timeline

I am putting together a timeline chart -- and I've tried to highlight the current month with a rectangle block that has an opacity.

https://jsfiddle.net/g89kuoe1/3/

```
    var date = new Date();
    var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
    var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);

    var currentMonth = itemRectsCurrentMonth
        .append('rect')
        .attr('class', 'currentMonth')
        //.selectAll('rect')
        .attr('x', function(d) {
            return x1(firstDay);
        })
        .attr('y', 0)
        .attr('width', function(d) {
            return x1(lastDay) - x1(firstDay);
        })
        .attr('height', function(d) {
            return y1(mainHeight);
        });

    /*
    currentMonth
        //.enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('class', 'currentMonth')
        .attr('x', function(d) {
            return x1(firstDay);
        })
        .attr('y', function(d) {
            return y1(mainHeight);
        })
        .attr('width', function(d) {
            return x1(lastDay) - x1(firstDay);
        })
        .attr('height', function(d) {
            return y1(mainHeight);
        })*/

    currentMonth.exit().remove();
```

-- this creates a blur effect

[image]

Comment: As you might have noticed, initially it renders correctly. The blur effect is a result of adding the `currentMonth` rect many times on brush adjustment - just inspect the blue rectangle in console and see there are tons of it.
Your code is too messy for me to see where is your mistake (or maybe I'm just lazy to properly analyze it), but your `currentMonth.exit().remove();` doesn't do anything. Generally speaking, `exit()` should be called in tandem with a `data()` call, which I do not see. That should serve as a good starting point for you to debug it further.

Comment: but there wouldn't be a data() part -- as its known data -- e.g. first day of current month, last day of current month -- and I know why its blurring - but how to fix it - not seen any examples close to this

Comment: I've saved a cut down version -- https://jsfiddle.net/p7u0983k/

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem by doing a remove first.

https://jsfiddle.net/a8ps1dk7/

```
    var date = new Date();
    var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
    var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);

    console.log("firstDay", firstDay);
    console.log("lastDay", lastDay);

    itemRectsCurrentMonth.selectAll(".currentMonth").remove();

    itemRectsCurrentMonth
        .append('rect')
        .attr('class', 'currentMonth')
        //.selectAll('rect')
        .attr('x', function(d) {
            return x1(firstDay);
        })
        .attr('y', 0)
        .attr('width', function(d) {
            return x1(lastDay) - x1(firstDay);
        })
        .attr('height', function(d) {
            return y1(mainHeight);
        });
```

Comment: If you will always have a single instance of `rect.currentMonth`, I'd suggest adding it once and only adjusting its `x` and `width` attributes rather than removing and adding it over and over.